# Changing ESP-12E NodeMCU to ESP-01S - how to trigger sketch?

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-leonardo, arduino-pro-micro

I had my sketch up and running with a NodeMCU and a Leonardo Pro Micro and decided I wanted to minimize the footprint of the project and use the smaller ESP-01S board instead.

The ESP-01S is programmed to send a push notification to Pushover and my old code works - the only problem is that I don't know how to trigger it from the Pro Micro.

With the NodeMCU I just setup it up to listen on Pin 2 and I triggered a high/low from my Pro Micro and it sent the push notification - at the moment as soon as I power the ESP-01S up it just sends the push notification over and over and doesn't see the connection from the Pro Micro to stop it doing this.

Here is my current code on the ESP-01S

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

// Wifi Settings
const char* ssid = "Redacted";
const char* password = "Redacted";
// Pushover settings
char pushoversite[] = "api.pushover.net";
char apitoken[] = "Redacted";
char userkey [] = "Redacted";
int length;
WiFiClient client;
void setup() {
  pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(0, LOW);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(10);

  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  // Print the IP address
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());

}

void loop()
{
if(digitalRead(5) == 1) pushover("Deployment Completed");
}

byte pushover(char *pushovermessage)
{
 String message = pushovermessage;

 length = 81 + message.length();

if(client.connect(pushoversite,80))
 {
   client.println("POST /1/messages.json HTTP/1.1");
   client.println("Host: api.pushover.net");
   client.println("Connection: close\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   client.print("Content-Length: ");
   client.print(length);
   client.println("\r\n");;
   client.print("token=");
   client.print(apitoken);
   client.print("&user=");
   client.print(userkey);
   client.print("&message=");
   client.print(message);
   while(client.connected())  
   {
     while(client.available())
     {
       char ch = client.read();
       Serial.write(ch);
     }
   }
   client.stop();
 }  
}
```

and my Leonardo Pro Micro code is as follows

```cpp
#include <HID-Project.h>
#include <HID-Settings.h>
int buttonPin;
int buttonPin2;
char chr;   // for incoming serial data, type char is signed 8-bit, -128 to 127, ASCII is char codes. Save 1 byte over type int.

void setup() {
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  BootKeyboard.begin();
  Keyboard.begin();
  Mouse.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);
  buttonPin = 4; //White Button
  buttonPin2 = 6; //Black Button
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
  delay(100);   //short wait time
  digitalWrite(5, LOW);
  }
```

Obviously I want the digital pin 5 of the Pro Micro to trigger the ESP-01 to send a push notification when it's trigger.

Just for the record I'm using a 3.3v Pro Micro btw so there's no issue with the voltage here, before I was using a Logic Converter with a 5v board.

I have the ESP-O1S setup with the 3V3 and EN are connected to the 3v VCC on the Pro Micro, the GND to GND and I tried IO0 and IO2 to Digital Pin 5 on the Pro Micro.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: why do you read pin 5 in esp8266?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use io 0 as the esp-01S pin wired to Micro, but change the logic for pull-up, because esp-01S has a pull-up resistor on io 0 of the esp8266. Use LOW to trigger the action and HIGH as normal state.

On Arduino Micro side set the output pin HIGH before you set it as OUTPUT. This will avoid the LOW state. While the Micro pin is in INPUT state after power-up, the pull-up resistor on esp-01S will pull io 0 HIGH.

Comment: Gotcha, so do I need to change any of this code on the ESP-01S?

void setup() {
  pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(0, LOW);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(10);

Comment: in esp8266 `pinMode(0, INPUT);` and `if (digitalRead(0) == LOW) pushover("Deployment Completed");`

Comment: Got it, cracked it, thanks Jaraj!

Comment: Just to double check, the correct way on the Leonardo to change the logic is to just set the pin write as HIGH in setup right? There's no way to flip it when you set it out as a Output (that I can see)

Comment: yes set it HIGH before setting it as output, to avoid the LOW state which would trigger the action